# Add the result of several broadcasts on a single activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

In my application I have a BroadCastque receives pushs notifications in the background, this push now open an activity with the information a request to be accepted, what happens is that at the same moment you are reading a request receive another app open on top in a new Intent.

```
public class BroadcastReceiverOneSignal extends BroadcastReceiver {

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

Bundle extras = intent.getBundleExtra("data");
try {
    JSONObject customJSON = new JSONObject(extras.getString("custom"));
    if(customJSON.has("a")){

        String id = customJSON.getJSONObject("a").getString(Constants.ID_CORRIDA);

        Intent i = new Intent(context, Activty.class);
        i.putExtra(Constants.ID, id);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the activity is in the foreground just change it's content. If not, start the activity.

You can acomplish this using a static boolean variable then change it's value in the activity's `onResume` and `onPause` methods.